# How exactly do iterators work? (multiple-choice)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm confused as to why the final answer (selection e.) is false in this multiple choice question:

```
Which of the following statements is the most accurate regarding linked lists?

a. Linked-lists take up more space than STL vectors because they allocate extra storage 
space for future growth.
b. The asymptotic complexity of inserting at the end of a doubly-linked list container 
storing only the pointer to the first element is O(1).
c. A loop in a singly-linked-list can be found in O(log(n)) time and O(n) memory overhead
d. A loop in a singly-linked-list can be found in O(n) time and O(1) memory overhead.
e. The number of elements in a linked-list is end_ptr -start_ptr + 1, where start_ptr points
to the first element in the linked list and end_ptr points to the last item of the linked-list.
```

That is, why aren't *both* d. and e. correct?  In what instances would an iterator return the size with `end_ptr-start_ptr+1`, and in what instances would it not?  Should the choice have stated `end_ptr-start_ptr` instead?

Comment: Where does this question come from? And is it talking about `std::list`, or *any* linked list?

Comment: Since the pointers to each element in a linked list are memory-location independent of each other, if you think (e) is *remotely* accurate you may be thinking of a vector instead of a list. It should not be among your list of considered candidates for the answer to this question.

Comment: Why is (d) supposed to be accurate?  ISTR you need O(n^2) time to do it in O(1) storage.

Comment: @BenVoigt Am I misreading (d)? Seems that `O(n)` is trivial to just traverse a linked list: `while (node) { /* do something with node */ node = node->next; }`

Comment: @Corbin: Yes, now what is `/* do something with node */` in order to detect a loop?

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, we are reading it differently. I think it's just a horribly worded way of a saying "There exists an algorithm for looping over a singly linked list in O(n) time and O(1) space." Not, "There exists an algorithm in O(n) time and O(1) space for determining if there is a circular linkage within a singly linked list." That would indeed have to be `O(n^2)`. (Actually, if you have meta-data of how long the list is, you could just traverse it until either the end of len + 1. If you hit the end before len + 1, then no loop. Otherwise, if you hit len + 1, it has a loop.)

Comment: @Corbin: Or the length is wrong.  I don't see why one form of metadata corruption is more likely than the other.  But O(stored length) would be sufficient to detect corruption.

Comment: @BenVoigt if you're looking for a loop, you're probably putting loops in it on purpose. But yes, if there's a bug that causes loops, there's just as likely other bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linked lists are not guaranteed to be contiguous (and in fact, never are -- at least not in a real-world scenario).

This means that subtracting their iterators cannot be a constant time operation (well, it could be, but not without making undesirable tradeoffs).

Typically the minus and plus operators are not defined on iterators unless it's a constant time operation.

---

Also, even if you could subtract them, iterators point one past the last element, not at the last element. This means that `length = end - begin`. There's no need for plus one.

For example, with a `std::vector`:

```
size_t len = v.end() - v.begin();
```

(Though you would usually just use `v.size()`.)

Comment: What do you mean "not guaranteed to be contiguous?"

Comment: @BobJohn The memory behind lists is not one giant block like in a vector, but rather links chained together where each part of the chain points off at some memory. Linked lists are never contiguous in practice. It would make you introduce too weird of tradeoffs (not to mention that calling them "linked" lists would then make no sense).

Comment: Thanks!  So, what other containers *are* guaranteed to be contiguous besides vectors?  How about an array?

Comment: @BobJohn arrays are arguably *the* contiguous data structure. All an array is after all is a chunk of memory. Arrays are, by definition, contiguous. It wouldn't make sense for `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` to not be next to each other. (And if that were the case, cache locality would be murdered.) Vectors are pretty much the only high level container guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: What about a data type which represents an array in shuffled order (fixed size)?  You could use pointers or indexes to link the nodes, just like an ordinary linked list.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not quite sure which thing that is a response to?

Comment: @Corbin: Counter-example to the "no real-world list is ever contiguous".

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, yes indeed then. But how likely are you to see that? I suppose I chose my words badly when I said "real world." What I really meant was "highly generic" or maybe better: "at least not with a traditional linked list."

Comment: @Corbin: I think the *real-world* terminology was fine, but you should have said *rarely* or *seldom* instead of *never*.  *Never* creates a very strong claim that's hard to back up.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike vectors, the items in a list are not stored in continuous locations. So a linked list.end() should be null to mark the end of the list. That is why you cannot get the list size by arithmetic. Also, the end points to an invalid item, one item past the last valid element.